# Prepare to segue when calloutAccessoryControlTapped (get data from parse.com)

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, mkmapview, segue, mkannotation

I've a problem with Annotation when clicked and send data to "Prepare to segue"

I've used this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Ristoranti"];

        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

            if (!error)
            {

                NSLog(@"QUERY -----> :%@", objects);


                for(NSMutableDictionary *note1 in objects) {
                    float realLatitude1 = [[note1 objectForKey:@"Latitudine"] floatValue];
                    float realLongitude1 = [[note1 objectForKey:@"Longitudine"] floatValue];

                    NSLog(@"(PARSE) Latitudine: %f", realLatitude1);
                    NSLog(@"(PARSE) Longitudine: %f", realLongitude1);


                    DisplayMap *displayMap = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];

                    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
                    theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude1;
                    theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude1;
                    displayMap.coordinate = theCoordinate;
                    displayMap.title = [note1 objectForKey:@"NomeLocale"];
                    displayMap.subtitle = [note1 objectForKey:@"Indirizzo"];
                    displayMap.icon = [note1 objectForKey:@"PinMappa"];
                    [_mapView setDelegate:self];
                    [_mapView addAnnotation:displayMap];
                }
            }
        }];
}
```

and:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[DisplayMap class]])
    {

        return nil;
    }

    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";

    MKAnnotationView *pinView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

    if (pinView == nil)
    {
        pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    else
        pinView.annotation = annotation;


    DisplayMap *myAnn = (DisplayMap *)annotation;
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:myAnn.icon];



    // Create a UIButton object to add on the
    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pinView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:rightButton];

    return pinView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    if ([(UIButton*)control buttonType] == UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure)
    {


        NSLog(@"The annotation tapped is: %@", view.annotation.title);


        NSUInteger index = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:view.annotation];

        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)index);


        //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Prova" sender:self];

    }  
}
```

and:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Prova"]) {

        DettagliAlberghi *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        DisplayMap *displayMap = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];

        displayMap.title = [note1 objectForKey:@"NomeLocale"];
        displayMap.subtitle = [note1 objectForKey:@"Indirizzo"];
        displayMap.icon = [note1 objectForKey:@"PinMappa"];
        displayMap.Telefono = [note1 objectForKey:@"Telefono"];
        displayMap.Email = [note1 objectForKey:@"Email"];
        displayMap.Sito = [note1 objectForKey:@"Sito"];
        displayMap.TipologiaLocale = [note1 objectForKey:@"TipologiaLocale"];
        displayMap.Cucina = [note1 objectForKey:@"Cucina"];
        displayMap.Vegano = [note1 objectForKey:@"Vegano"];
        displayMap.Valutazione = [note1 objectForKey:@"Valutazione"];
        displayMap.Latitudine = [note1 objectForKey:@"Latitudine"];
        displayMap.Longitudine = [note1 objectForKey:@"Longitudine"];
        displayMap.Anteprima1 = [note1 objectForKey:@"Anteprima1"];
        displayMap.Anteprima2 = [note1 objectForKey:@"Anteprima2"];
        displayMap.Anteprima3 = [note1 objectForKey:@"Anteprima3"];
        displayMap.FaceB = [note1 objectForKey:@"Facebook"];
        displayMap.Twit = [note1 objectForKey:@"Twitter"];




        NSLog(@"Dettagli Ristorante: \n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@", displayMap.title, displayMap.subtitle, displayMap.Telefono, displayMap.Email, displayMap.Sito, displayMap.TipologiaLocale, displayMap.Cucina, displayMap.Vegano, displayMap.Valutazione, displayMap.Latitudine, displayMap.Longitudine, displayMap.Anteprima1, displayMap.Anteprima2, displayMap.Anteprima3, displayMap.FaceB, displayMap.Twit);




        destViewController.recipes = displayMap;

    }
}
```

I would like to understand how to recognize some annotation is pressed and send the data to the next page through "PrepareForSegue".
Does anyone know how to help me? I'm going crazy.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will simply want to use the mapView:didSelectAnnotationView: delegate call.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452393-mapview

From in mapView:didSelectAnnotationView, call the segue call via the performSegueWithIdentifier.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Prova" sender:self];
```

Assuming you setup "note1" from within mapView:didSelectAnnotationView based on the annotation selected.

Comment: without having to use: NSUInteger index = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:view.annotation]; ?? PS: I'm taking data from Parse ... and I do not understand how to send them to PrepareForSegue

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Do you need the index of it specifically?  If you just want the annotation then:  view.annotation should be all you need...?   (Actually, you've already got the prepareForSegue referencing the new controller, and passing through the "recipes".. so I'm not sure what else you need?)

Comment: I've modified the code: "[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Prova" sender:view.annotation.title];" and in PrepareForSegue I added: "MKAnnotationView * annotationView = sender;". Now when I click on Pin I get the name of local, but in all recipes to pass to the next view I get (null). I do not understand what is wrong

Comment: You're instantiating the DisplayMap/annotations in the viewDidLoad, but in the prepareForSegue you're instantiating it again, with a note1 object.  Unless you either use the DisplayMap subclass or have note1 being assigned somewhere (which is where?), this will be null....

Comment: Yes, in viewDidLoad, I read the coordinates so that you assign pin to display on the map ... but after that I need when I click I go to read and send data that are present in "PrepareForSegue" but I do not understand what is wrong ... I incollatto all the code that I used